# SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar does not return value from 2nd row in a table

Tags: c#

I am trying a simple windows form which retrieves the value from a SQL Server CE database. There are 2 columns, `name` and `company` in the `Employee` table.

The rows are as follows :

```
Name Company
XXX    ABC
YYY    DEF
```

I used the following code to retrieve data from db :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conn);

    SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select company from EMPLOYEES where name = @name", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",textBox1.Text);

    con.Open();

    try
    {
        object obj = new object();
        obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        label1.Text = (string)obj;
    }
    finally
    {
    }
```

The above code works fine for the 1st row in the table i.e when I give XXX in the text box, ABC is displayed in the form. But when I enter YYY in the text box, null is returned. I am an amateur in C#. Just trying a few simple examples to learn. Please help me out with this. Thanks

in advance.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that there's no whitespace in your input or database values?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes. When I run the same query in SQL management studio, the result is retrieved for all the rows.

Comment: make sure in your finally you close your con object.  LEAK.....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that too. I closed the con obj and also the cmd object once. nothing worked till now. Connection seems fine since the 1st row works fine i.e when I enter XXX, ABC is retrieved

Comment: Are you sure the name is `YYY` and not `YYY ` (empty spaces at the end?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I am sure. As I said earlier, the query runs fine in SQL management studio.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue` and check if `textBox1.Text` is really what you think it is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I debugged the entire code having breakpoint from the button click event. The value for textBox1.Text is YYY. But the value for the obj is NULL which is why there is nothing displayed in the label

Comment: What's `conn`? Are you sure it's the same thing you're using for SQL Management Studio?

Comment: conn is the parameter for connection string with 'string' datatype. Yes, I am sure I am using the same values as in SQL studio.

Comment: Mind telling us what the values are? I suspect you're sure about something that's wrong

Comment: I didn't get you. You mean you want the values in my tables ?

Comment: No, what is the value of `conn` and what are the server properties you used to connect to the database from SQLS Studio.

Comment: From app.config :<connectionStrings>
        <add name="con"
            connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\employees.sdf;Password=partha_23"
            providerName="Microsoft.SqlServerCe.Client.3.5" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: I still need to know how you're connecting to the database from SQLS Studio. Also, you're not overwriting `CurrentDomain("DataDirectory")` somewhere, are you?

Comment: Use SQL Server Profiler to see the SQL that is being executed, see if you can spot the problem. You can copy that SQL to SQL Management Studio to see what results it is coming back with.

Comment: @DourHighArch I didnt overwrite that. I didnt understand the 1st part of the question though.

Comment: @marc, that is good advice but since he is calling `ExecuteScalar` on `select company from EMPLOYEES where name = 'YYY'` that can't be the problem.

Comment: @Partha, your question shows multiple rows of your Employees table, but your code only gets the first column of the first row; where did you get those row values from and how did you insert them? From SQL Server Management Studio? When you opened your database from SQLSMS you had to type in a connection string or a path; I need to know what you typed in; it's in the Database Properties from the SQLSMS object explorer. I can't see your screen; you have to tell me what you have.

Comment: I inserted values into the table using insert statements in SQL MS. I don't understand the 2nd part of your question properly. But from what you said there is only my system's local path there. I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Comment: What database did you “inserted values into the table using insert statements in SQL MS”? I suspect it was not `|DataDirectory|\employees.sdf` but I will never know until you tell me what database you connected to in SQL Studio.

Answer (score 3):

This is by Design. `SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar` Method returns only the 1st row.

Source: `SqlCeCommand.ExecuteScalar` **[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.executescalar%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**:

> Executes the query and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set that is returned by the query. Extra columns or rows
>   are ignored.

Use the `ExecuteReader()` if you expect and need to process more than 1 row in your resultset.

Answer (score 1):

ExecuteScalar()  is designed to return a scalar value (a single value). This is usually used for Count(*) to return number of rows.

From your code it looks like you are trying to return more then one row. If you want to iterate through a dataset then you should utilize the `SqlCeDataReader` class

```
SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select company from EMPLOYEES where name = @name");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",textBox1.Text);

cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();

SqlCeDataReader dr = selectSQL.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
  {
    label1.Text = dr["ColumnName"].ToString();
  }
dr.Close();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the XXX row of the table in SQL Management Studio:

```
update EMPLOYEES set Company = 'ZYX' where Name = 'XXX'
```

Then try your form again and see what value it returns for XXX. If it is still ABC, then you're not connecting to the right database.

BTW, I tried your code myself, and it returns the YYY row fine, so I think it is likely a data/connection issue.

(FYI, I had to make this an answer rather than a comment because it won't let me comment yet.)